# Chat application: Using Django with sockjs-tornado and redis

Tags: django, websocket, redis, tornado, sockjs

I am trying to write chat application, here are some desing thoughts:
Django doing main website serving.
Sockjs-tornado serves chat and between them I would like to setup redis.
 When sockjs-tornado receives message in chat, it processes it and sends to other connected clients and also puts it in redis, so Django can save this message in persistent database. I know I should use pubsub  functionallity of redis. I know how to setup it in tornado (brukva library), but how can I subscribe to redis' channel in django? So I can receive message in django and save it to database? Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i'm  not know how sockjs use, but this example illustrate how to save in django model
#in tornado

```
import brukva  
import tornado.web  
import tornado.websocket

c = brukva.Client()  
c.connect()

class MessagesHandler(tornado.websoket.WebsocketHandler):

    def open(self):
        #....

    def handle_request(self, response):
        pass

    def on_message(self, message):
        #....
        c.publish(self.channel, json.dumps({
            "sender": self.sender_name,
            "text": message,
        }))

        http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(
              '/to/django_project/url/chat_save_base/',

                method="POST",
                body=urllib.urlencode({
                "message": message.encode("utf-8"),
                "sender": self.sender.name,
            })
        http_client.fetch(request, self.handle_request)
```

#in django_url

```
url(r'/to/django_project/url/chat_save_base/','app.my_view')
```

#my_view

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt  
from messages.models import Message

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):  
    message_text = request.POST.get("message")  
    sender = User.objects.get(id=request.POST.get("sender_id"))  

    message = Message()
    message.text = message_text
    message.sender_id = sender_id    
    message.save()
```

source for additional info:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/160123/

Comment: do you have a python 3 solution too?